# Redirect in MVC does not work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-redirect

I have the following code:

```
var redirectIp = string.Format("{0}{1}", Session["CurrentHost"], ip.PathAndQuery);
return new RedirectResult(redirectIp);
```

When I check the value of redirectIP it gives me:

```
redirectIp  "127.0.0.1:84/Administration/Accounts/ShowSummary?ds=0001"  string
```

However when I step through the code the browser opens and gives me the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:84/Administration/Accounts/127.0.0.1:84/Administration/Accounts/ShowSummary?ds=0001
```

I am totally confused. Anyone have any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is how urls, http and browsers work. You forgot the protocol part, so the redirect actually **does** work as expected, given the url that you are redirecting to.

```
var redirectIp = string.Format("http://{0}{1}", Session["CurrentHost"], ip.PathAndQuery);
return new RedirectResult(redirectIp);
```

This will work better for now, but to be able to also cover https, you're better off storing the protocol part in a session variable along with the hostname.